# Python 3 | AttributeError

Tags: python, windows

When I start my Python Script I get the error:
AttributeError: module 'select' has no attribute 'poll'

I'm using Windows! It is only for the Raspberry Pi?
The error:
[image]

So i added the code. I hope it helps.
The fauxmo.py script:

```
import email.utils
import requests
import select
import socket
import struct
import sys
import time
import urllib
import uuid
import logging


def dbg(msg):
    logging.debug(msg)


##HERE
class poller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.poller = select.poll()
        self.targets = {}

    def add(self, target, fileno = None):
        if not fileno:
            fileno = target.fileno()
        self.poller.register(fileno, select.POLLIN)
        self.targets[fileno] = target

    def remove(self, target, fileno = None):
        if not fileno:
            fileno = target.fileno()
        self.poller.unregister(fileno)
        del(self.targets[fileno])

    def poll(self, timeout = 0):
        ready = self.poller.poll(timeout)
        num = len(ready)
        for one_ready in ready:
            target = self.targets.get(one_ready[0], None)
            if target:
                target.do_read(one_ready[0])
        return num
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Please post, at the very least, the relevant code snippet and full error traceback in your question

Comment: I checked, `select.poll` is available on Linux

Comment: Your error should be plain text. Why is it an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`poll` is a unix-only function. It is not available on Windows.

Comment: Raspberry Pi-es use linux, so `poll` is available on all Raspberry Pi-es.